# Using Power Query GUI in PowerBI with DirectQuery Data

Tags: json, powerbi, dax, powerquery, directquery

Our composite model using directquery to get the data from the first layer of dataset since want to make sure the tables from golden dataset will not be modified by the users. (shown below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx49x.png)

However, if we hope to give users opportunity to create their own tables if the tables we provide are not enough (need extra join, add column, extra calculation, etc)

I understand that we can use DAX to create table
https://radacad.com/creating-a-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-table-constructor

But we really hope to use the GUI functionality in 'transform data' (power query).
Especially we have a lot of JSON value in the dataset and it could be a life saver for people have no experience in coding (Neither power query nor DAX is easy to learn let's be honest)

My question is -
Can I duplicate (or refer) the table from direct query and make changes on it in the power query GUI? That way user won't be directly modifying tables, but still able to create and add the tables that user need upon my original dataset.